# Я былa в Москве but if a town name ends in ё?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

I undestand that it is correct to write: "Я былa в Москве" but if a name ends with "ё" would it still be correct to end the sentence with an "e"?

"Я былa в Мальмe (Мальмё), Швеция"

Comment: According to the local russian teacher, she claims that if a geographic location ends with an "-a". The "-a" will be converted into an "-e" (See москва example) and all other names will stay as they are. That means according to her that: москва --> B москвe
мальмё --> B мальмё
Сочи --> B Сочи Can someone confirm this phenomenon to me?

Comment: well, e.g. "Останкино => в Останкине" is also correct (this rules mostly concerns Russian toponyms, ending in -ово, -ево, -ино); as to "Мальмё", you may safely *spell* it as "в Мальме", dropping the dots (though not recommended, as the word is rare), but nonetheless you should always *read* it as "в Мальмё"

Answer (score 6):

*Мальмё* is a foreign word which has no declension. In every case you should say just *Мальмё* and nothing else.

That is "*Я была в Мальмё, Швеция*" or maybe "*Я была в Мальмё, в Швеции*".

Answer (score 4):

There are many [Russian words that are indeclinable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Russian_indeclinable_nouns).  So it's simply: *Я былa в Мальмё.*

For foreign city names specifically, you can take some of the wisdom on
 [this question on the declension of foreign person names](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/7223/non-russian-names-to-decline-or-not-to-decline).

There are fairly exact rules on the intonation and final ending combinations that make a word indeclinable, and some exceptions, and some disagreement in some edge cases if we actually look at the data descriptively.  (They tend to be foreign words, abbreviations etc.)  But for a language learner I think it does not make sense to focus more than minimal effort on learning the rules explicitly - just see the examples.